# How can I see pointer value change in python using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I want to implement void function in C and in that function I will change pointer value, like this:

```
void func(int* k){ *k = 9; }
```

As you can see, here I am changing k value, let's say with 9. How can I write this function in python using ctypes so I can see what is the changed value is, in C. lets say following python code example

```
import ctypes
d = ctypes.CDLL(r'mydll.dll')
d.our_function.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
```

As you can see there is no return, so how can I see in my python call, that my value is changed?
sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Note your argtypes is incorrect.  It needs to be a sequence.  `(x)` is not a tuple; `(x,)` (or even `x,`) is a 1-tuple.  The comma makes the tuple.

Comment: Also, you're not actually calling the function :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate an `int` yourself in Python and pass its address, like this:

```
k = c_int()
d.our_function(byref(k))
print(k.value)
```